# Read muti-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array, typeerror

I am having a hard time reading below array into my javascript function

```
 <form action="/myAction" method="post" name ="myForm", id ="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="myList[1][NAME]" value="John" />
  <input type="text" name="myList[1][AGE]" value="20" />
  <input type="text" name="myList[2][NAME]" value="Mike" />
  <input type="text" name="myList[2][AGE]" value="30" />
  <input type="text" name="myList[3][NAME]" value="Sam" />
  <input type="text" name="myList[3][AGE]" value="40" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

When I tried to read the myList in javascript, I always get

```
TypeError: document.myForm.myList is undefined
```

How do I correctly read the above array in javascript ? Thank you for your time.

**Edit:** I wish to create myList[][] which will store all my form data and in javascript I plan to do some calculation on the values of the list.

**Edit2:** I have table of data with hundreds of rows and few columns, I wish to reduce the number of HTTP params being passed to server in the POST request. This is why I am trying to put all data in one element. However not able to read properly in javascript.

Comment: What do you intend to do? `document.myForm.myList` will try to find a field with `name` as `myList` inside `myForm`. Apparently, there is no such field with name `myList`

Comment: I wish to get the whole myList in javascript and do some calculation.

Comment: So the names of your inputs are i.e. "myList[1][NAME]", aren't they?

Comment: So there is no array. Every input has its own name.

Comment: @RaviGupta Still unclear on what you need to do exactly, could you elaborate in the question itself?

Comment: @DevWurm so how I do go about creating myList[][] array ?

Comment: @RaviGupta do you want to create a node array from all the input fields? In this case the name of them is not this relevant

Comment: so giving name like myList[][Name] will work?

Comment: is that hardcode names in your form ? if so why you do that way.

Comment: @A.T. I have table of entries with hundred of rows and few columns, I wish to put all data in one element.

Comment: can you use jquery library?

Comment: Yes, I have that option